# JSP project in RAD + Websphere, javascript changes lost

Tags: eclipse, jsp, websphere

I'm working on JSP project in RAD 8.5.5 (when I tried to switch to Eclipse Kepler I've had the same issue) and WebSphere 8.0 
When I change something in external JavaScript files which contain my own JavaScript functions I begin to get an error - 'function non defined' or even I lost part of code of this *.js page when I try to debug it in Chrome. 
When I publish it to the server or rebuild it doesn't help. When I try to work without javascript cache in Chrome it doesn't work. Only after certain amount of time it begins to work. When I make changes in embedded JavaScript code on JSP page I haven't any problem, only I use my own function in external files.

What can it be? I lost a lot of time on this issue and it's annoying. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this issue you should do as following:

1.Prevent from browser to cache pages, in Chrome you can do it only developer tools are open : [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

2.Perform 'Build project'  from Eclipse(RAD). In some difficult case you have to do 'clean' on the server.

3.If you encounter unexpected delay while publishing try to delete all Breakpoints and Expressions from debug perspective.

4.Sometimes your server turning off and on every minutes by itself. To stop such behavior restart it in usual mode and then restart in debug mode.

Hope it will helpful to somebody.